# Anonymous Users cannot view item properties

Tags: 2013, anonymous-authentication, list-view-web-part

I have a page on an externally facing SharePoint 2013 site which is accessible by anonymous users.  On this page is a list view web part pointing at a List to which anonymous users should also have view item access.  Anonymous users can see the page, and the web part, and the items the web part can show.  However, if they click the "view properties" link (title) of an item it pops up the dialog box AND prompts them for login.  If they do not login (they should not be prompted) they get an error in the dialog about not being authorized.

How can I get it to the point where anonymous users can view the item properties in a dialog (or even on a new page)?

PS - As a bonus I don't want to show anonymous users (or even non-contributor authenticated users) certain fields on the display form.

**Update**

I scrapped this altogether due to a lack of solution.  Now I just display all the items in a listview on the page and hide the columns I don't want anonymous users to see.  Less visually appealing but it works.  Maybe in the future I'll work something out with data form webpart and jQuery or something.

Comment: Your PS suggest that you've changed the display form. How has this been done? It's probably that change which demands the authentication.

Comment: Switching back to the default display form did not make a difference.  I thought the same thing.  Also, other security trimmed controls on the site do not trigger authentication.